# Is the 2-dimensional Gauss-Bonnet theorem applicable in higher dimensions?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

This is a cross-post of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3691891/272127) MSE post that users commented that it is appropriate for MO.

> I want to know
>
> > **Question:** Is the 2-dimensional Gauss-Bonnet theorem applicable (any topological or geometrical obstruction) in higher dimensions?
>
> My idea is that one can consider 2-dimensional embedded submanifolds of $(M^n,g)$ and then applying Gauss-Bonnet theorem to all of such submanifolds then collecting these information together somehow and finding a topological or geometrical property (like fundamental group, Homology groups, etc.). Is that possible at all?

Comment: See Wikipedia on the [Chern–Gauss–Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), which is an even-dimensional generalization of Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: I know about Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.I want to use 2−dimensional Gauss-Bonnet to deduce a higher dimensional result.

Comment: Isn't the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem a higher dimensional result???

Comment: I am not aware of any proof of Chern--Gauss--Bonnet, or any other theorem, that arises by simultaneous gluing of all surfaces inside the manifold. I think that nothing is known about that question.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been down-voted? What kind of details needed to clarify the problem and prevent from closing? Is this a vague question?

Comment: I think it is down-voted  for being too vague. In the present form, it is not answerable. As for how many details you need to add, I do not know, since I am not sure what the question really is.

Comment: The valid @ThiKu's answer shows that the question is not vague for him and who up-voted his answer. My question is: Can one get a nice result (topological or geometrical) by knowing curvature and topology  of all 2-dim sub-manifolds of $(M^n,g)$?

Comment: I think the wording of the question is unclear. You're asking whether the 2-dimensional Gauss-Bonnet theorem is ever used to prove a theorem about higher dimensional manifolds.

Comment: When you say "higher dimensions" what do you mean?  i.e. higher than what?

Comment: For arbitrary dimensions higher than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some applications of Gauß-Bonnet in foliations and laminations of 3-manifolds.

The first result that comes to mind is [Candel’s Uniformization Theorem](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1993_4_26_4_489_0.pdf), which gives necessary and sufficient conditions for a lamination to admit a leafwise hyperbolic metric. The proof uses Gauß-Bonnet in a nontrivial way. (A shorter exposition is in Chapter 7 of Calegari: “Foliatuons and the Geometry of 3-manifolds”.)